# Webview regresar el historial

Tags: java, android

como puedo hacer para cuando presione el `button` de atras no me manda en el activity inicial de la  app por ejemplo  (Si en mi webview tenia abierto enlace 1,2,3,4.. por cada vez que presione el boton atras debería volver 3,2,1..) pero directo me mando en la activity inicial.

Estoy usando  webview dentro de un fragment !

aquí esta mi código:

```
    WebView webView;

String urls="http://www.*********.com/";
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.informacion, container, false);

    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl(urls);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return view;
```

Comment: No te mate la aplicación a que te refieres, se cierra? si es así revisa el LogCat

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys por tu repuesta , la verdad me exprese mal ...  no es que cierra la app , pero me manda en el primer activity, aun si había abierto 3 o 4 enlaces.. me manda directo en la pagina inicia, Me gustaría poder hacer marcha atrás cada vez que presione el buton BACK... espero que me exprese mejor Gracias

Comment: Es el comportamiento normal, si das "back" cierra la activity que contiene el WebView. Lo que deseas es que cargue la pagina que anteriormente fue cargada?

Comment: si exactamente , eso que deseo

Comment: ok de hecho cambié el titulo porque existia una pregunta con el mismo titulo. @user62207

Answer (score 1):

El hecho que te encuentres en un `Fragment` es irrelevante, lo que debes realizar es implementar que cuando detecte tu dispositivo la tecla "back", revise en el `WebView` si tiene un historial de carga de paginas y puede regresar, si llega a la última instancia puedes cerrar tu aplicación mediante `finish();`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean response;
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            response = true;
        }else{
            finish();
            response = super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }else{
        response = super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return response;
}
```